# How do I concatenate a var in another var string in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to alert the address2 with the value taken from the input field. I keep getting nothing. Please help

HTML

```
<form>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="city" type="text">
  </div>

    <button id="locationWeather" onclick="check()" type="button">Submit</button>

</form>
```

MY SCRIPT

```
       function check() {
           var address = $("#city").val();
           var address2 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +address "&key=YOUR_API_KEY";

           alert(address);
           alert(address2);
           }
</script>
```

Comment: You're missing a + sign after address.

Comment: Open up the developer console in your browser. It will point you to your error.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a "+" symbol. Keep in mind that the placeholder doesn't count as a value. I would just add that street as the initial value and allow the user to change it if necessary. Last thing, you need to URI encode the string or the value may not be called correctly on your next function.

```
function check() {
       var address = $("#city").val();
       var address2 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + encodeURIComponent(address) + "&key=YOUR_API_KEY";

       alert(address);
       alert(address2);
       }
```